# How to extract the first and final words from a string?

Tags: python, string, split, extract

I have a small problem with something I need to do in school...

My task is the get a raw input string from a user (`text = raw_input()`)
and I need to print the first and final words of that string.

Can someone help me with that? I have been looking for an answer all day...

Comment: By final word do you mean last word? Please mention the sample example

Comment: Is the last word in `"Hello World!"` the string `"World!"` or the word `"World"` ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have to firstly convert the string to `list` of words using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and then you may access it like:

```
>>> my_str = "Hello SO user, How are you"
>>> word_list = my_str.split()  # list of words

# first word  v              v last word
>>> word_list[0], word_list[-1]
('Hello', 'you')
```

**From Python 3.x**, you may simply do:

```
>>> first, *middle, last = my_str.split()
```

Answer (score 24):

If you are using Python 3, you can do this:

```
text = input()
first, *middle, last = text.split()
print(first, last)
```

All the words except the first and last will go into the variable `middle`.

Comment: Cool, first time I see this feature.

Comment: Nice. If middle words were also required, it is very clean approach

Comment: This is nice, though it fails in the edge case of a 1-word sentence (where arguably that 1 word should be returned as both the first and the last word).

Comment: @JohnColeman, In this case, it errors out with `ValueError: not enough values to unpack`, which IMHO is a reasonable interpretation of "cannot split a word at a whitespace when such word does not have whitespace".

Answer (score 8):

Let's say `x` is your input. Then you may do:

```
 x.partition(' ')[0]
 x.partition(' ')[-1]
```

Comment: [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) will only chop `x` once (so, you'll get the first word, and then the rest of the sentence, not the last word).

Comment: @wildwilhelm: There is a possibility that this answer is what OP expects as there is no clarity on the definition of *final words*. As a matter of doubt, answer should not be down-voted

Comment: True, I agree that the question wording is ambiguous.  Downvote retracted.

Comment: What's not clear about first and final? This answer will only give the first and *second* words, no the final if there are more than two words...

Answer (score 7):

You would do:

```
print text.split()[0], text.split()[-1]
```

Answer (score 5):

Some might say, there is never too many answer's using regular expressions (in this case, this looks like the worst solutions..):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "Hello SO user, How are you"
>>> matches = re.findall(r'^\w+|\w+$', string)
>>> print(matches)
['Hello', 'you']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use .split and pop to retrieve the words from a string.
use "0" to get the first word and "-1" for the last word.

```
string = str(input())
print(string.split().pop(0))
print(string.split().pop(-1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass your string into the following **function**:

```
def first_and_final(str):
    res = str.split(' ')
    fir = res[0]
    fin = res[len(res)-1]
    return([fir, fin])
```

**Usage**:

```
first_and_final('This is a sentence with a first and final word.')
```

**Result**:

```
['This', 'word.']
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possible implementation, which does **not** use split()

```
text = 'hello how are you?'
first = text[:text.find(' ')]
last = text[text.rfind(' ') + 1:]
```

Be aware, this has a lot of problems with edge cases (empty string, one word, etc)